# PySpark escapeQuotes=False still escapes quotes

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

**Problem:** While writing the dataframe as csv, I do not want to escape quotes. However, setting `escapeQuotes=False` doesn't seem to be working.

Mentioned below is an example case:

**DataPrep:**

```
from pyspark.sql.types import StructType, StructField, StringType, IntegerType
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession, functions as func

spark = SparkSession.builder.appName("test").getOrCreate()

data = [("James", "Smith"),
    ("Michael", "Rose"),
  ]

schema = StructType([ \
    StructField("firstname",StringType(),True), \
    StructField("lastname",StringType(),True)
  ])
 
df = spark.createDataFrame(data=data,schema=schema)
df.show(truncate=False)
```

Output:

```
+---------+--------+
|firstname|lastname|
+---------+--------+
|James    |Smith   |
|Michael  |Rose    |
+---------+--------+
```

**Adding column with Newline Character**

```
def create_column_with_newline(elem):
    return f'"{elem["firstname"]}\n{elem["lastname"]}"'


columnWithNewlineUDF = func.udf(create_column_with_newline)

df = df.withColumn('newline_col', columnWithNewlineUDF(func.struct('firstname', 'lastname')))
df.show()
```

Output:

```
+---------+--------+-----------------+
|firstname|lastname|      newline_col|
+---------+--------+-----------------+
|    James|   Smith|    "James
Smith"|
|  Michael|    Rose|   "Michael
Rose"|
+---------+--------+-----------------+
```

**Writing csv with escapeQuotes=False**

```
df.coalesce(1).write.csv('test.tsv', mode='overwrite', sep='\t', header=True, encoding='UTF-8', escapeQuotes=False)
```

Output:

```
firstname   lastname    newline_col
James   Smith   "\"James
Smith\""
Michael Rose    "\"Michael
Rose\""
```

As you can see, the `newline_col` is written with escaped quotes :-(

Expected Output:

```
firstname   lastname    newline_col
James   Smith   "James
Smith"
Michael Rose    "Michael
Rose"
```

Comment: Let me see if I understood, the final value should be ""James
Smith"", twice quotes?

Comment: No. It should be "James Smith"

Answer (score 1):

Just remove the quotes from UDF:

```
def create_column_with_newline(elem):
    #      f'"{elem["firstname"]}\n{elem["lastname"]}"'
    return f'{elem["firstname"]}\n{elem["lastname"]}'
```

Output:

```
firstname   lastname    newline_col
James   Smith   "James
Smith"
Michael Rose    "Michael
Rose"
```

Excel visualization:

[image: excel]

Comment: No that doesn't help! I need the string in that column to start and end with DoubleQuotes. This allows me to open the output file in numbers and see multi-line cells.

Comment: Yeah, I updated the question to show what output I got, is it right?

Answer (score 0):

setting these two options worked for me

```
.option("quote","")
.option("escapeQuotes",false)
```